# Why does my regex work on RegexPlanet and regex101 but not in my code?

Tags: java, regex

Given the string `#100=SAMPLE('Test','Test',` I want to extract `100` and `Test`. I created the regular expression `^#(\d+)=SAMPLE\('([\w-]+)'.*` for this purpose.

I tested the regex on [RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/6akvh6) and [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/wP6aP4/1). Both tools give me the expected results, but when I try to use it in my code I don't get matches. I used the following snippet for testing the regex:

```
final String line = "#100=SAMPLE('Test','Test',";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^#(\\d+)=SAMPLE\\('([\\w-]+)'.*");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

System.out.println(matcher.matches());
System.out.println(matcher.find());
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

The output is

```
true
false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:496)
    at Test.main(Test.java:15)
```

I used Java 8 for compiling and running the program. Why does the regex work with the online tools but not in my program?

Comment: If you're using both `matches` and `find` in the same `Matcher`, you should `reset` between them.

Comment: remove `find`, and do if matches. - regex is stateful.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic! I didn't know about this behaviour. If you write your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object allows you to query it several times, so that you can find the expression, get the groups, find the expression again, get the groups, and so on.

This means that it keeps state after each call - both for the groups that resulted from a successful match, and the position where to continue searching.

When you run two matching/finding methods consecutively, what you have is:

1. `matches()` - Matches at the beginning of the string, sets the groups.
2. `find()` - tries to find the next occurrence of the pattern after the previously matched/found occurrence, sets the groups.

But of course, in your case, the text doesn't contain *two* occurrences of the pattern, only one. So although `matches()` was successful and set proper groups, the `find()` then fails to find another match, and the groups are invalid (the groups are not accessible after a failed match/find).

And that's why you get the error message.

Now, if you're just playing around with this, to see the difference between `matches` and `find`, then there is nothing wrong with having both of them in the program. But you need to use `reset()` between them, which will cause `find()` not to try to continue from where `matches()` stopped (which will always fail if `matches()` succeeded). Instead, it will start scanning from the start, as if you had a fresh `Matcher`. And it will succeed and give you groups.

But as other answers here hinted, if you're not just trying to compare the results of `matches` and `find`, but just wanted to match your pattern and get the results, then you should choose only *one* of them.

- `matches()` will try to match the entire string. For this reason, if it succeeds, running `find()` after it will never succeed - because it starts searching at the end of the string. If you use `matches()`, you don't need anchors like `^` and `$` at the beginning and the end of your pattern.
- `find()` will try to match anywhere in the string. It will start scanning from the left, but doesn't require that the actual match start there. It is also possible to use it more than once.
- `lookingAt()` will try to match at the beginning of the string, but will not necessarily match the complete string. It's like having an `^` anchor at the beginning of your pattern.

So you choose which one of these is appropriate for you, and use it, and then you can use the groups. Always test that the match succeeded before attempting to use the groups!

Answer (score 1):

As the @RealSkeptic mentioned, you should remove the call to `matcher.find()` in your code, which was advancing the matcher before you had a chance to find all the groups and output them to the console.  The rest of your code remains as is:

```
final String line = "#100=SAMPLE('Test','Test',";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^#(\\d+)=SAMPLE\\('([\\w-]+)'.*");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

System.out.println(matcher.matches());
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
```

**Output:**

```
true
100
Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this one, if I understood correctly, this is what you were trying to achieve:

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String line = "#100=SAMPLE('Test','Test',";
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^#(\\d+)=SAMPLE\\('([\\w-]+)'.*");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);

        if (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```